# Make HTML 'value' attribute a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to turn the output of the HTML input value into a clickable link.

Currently, it looks like: `<input type="email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" value="<?php echo $row_rsContactDetails['contactEmail']; ?>">`

I've tried using PHP and JavaScript to create the link but this just ended up displaying the HTML code verbatim.

Can it be done, and if so, how?

Comment: `<a href="link here">CLICK</a>`?

Comment: I've tried this one. Using double quotes splits the output but if you change the double quotes to single quotes it outputs what's written rather than a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to enter the link to output as value, you need a workaround
here is my suggestion:

https://jsfiddle.net/4w58ed3o/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <input type="email" id="myinput" value="default@email.com">
  <a href="#" id="mylink"></a>
</div>
<button id="myswitcher">Edit</button>
```

JS:

```
let input = document.querySelector('#myinput');
let link = document.querySelector('#mylink');
let myswitcher = document.querySelector('#myswitcher');

let setLink = () => {
    link.innerHTML = input.value;
  link.setAttribute('href', 'mailto:' + input.value);
}
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    setLink();
});

setLink();

myswitcher.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.box').classList.add('editable');
  input.focus();
});

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    document.querySelector('.box').classList.remove('editable');
});
```

CSS

```
input, a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;  
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: transparent;
}
input:focus, a:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.box input {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.box.editable a {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.box.editable input {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

I made a working example of implementation for you, substitute data from the server and be inspired by my solution.

Comment: Didn't need the CSS. With a couple of minor adjustments to suit, this works perfectly. Going to have a play with it as the page it will be on will also have a phone number (which I want clickable) and a possible second email address. Excellent work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript/jquery to achieve the same.

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" value="LINK HERE">
<span id="output"></span>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var str = "LINK TITLE HERE";
     var valueToLink = $(".form-control").val() //fetches the string to be converted to 
    //link
     var result = str.link(valueToLink);
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
   })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You could also hook up the above logic to an event call, e.g, button click.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible, but you can try this. And you can put `<?php echo $row_rsContactDetails['contactEmail']; ?>` in place to "SOME TEXT" as well.

```
<a href="<?php echo $row_rsContactDetails['contactEmail']; ?>">SOME TEXT</a>
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it just outputs the whole thing as a 'string'.

Comment: Do you even got PHP on the server? anyway this code is wrong, you can't give email address as a href without protocol (in this case `mailto:`).

Comment: @FlashThunder: I think you may be misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. PHP is set up correctly. If I use `<a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_rsContactDetails['contactEmail']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsContactDetails['contactEmail']; ?></a>` it displays correctly. I'm trying to use this code in the _value_ attribute in an HTML `input` tag.

Comment: @MartySmartyPants yeah I am totally lost now :D not sure what you are asking about, removed my answer. I guess you need to clarify your question.